# Logic: What is the word for the sentence inside a negation?

Tags: logic

Conjunction has "conjunct", there are also words for the components of disjunctions and conditionals.  But what about for negation and biconditional?

Comment: Negated sentence and equivalent sentences.

Comment: Negation is often (particularly by constructivists) *defined* as $\neg P \equiv P \Rightarrow \bot$.  In this case, $P$ could be referred to as the premise or antecedent of the contradiction or whatever term you like for implications.

Comment: For negation, my limited knowledge of Latin leads me to think the operand should be called the "negand", and a google search gives a bit of support for that. I wouldn't recommend using "negand" unless you want to irritate your readers. For the biconditional or equality I don't think we can even pretend that the Romans or the Greeks had a word for the operands. Why do you ask?

Comment: @RobArthan I got to a point in my writing where typing "the negated sentence, the ... the sentence under the negation" felt clunky on the keyboard.  I won't use it much, but it feels like the kind of thing that *should* exist.

Comment: @Addem: I'd write "the operand of $\lnot$", if that works. Or if something like $\lnot\phi$ is there in front of you, just write $\phi$. But I appreciate that those suggestions may not work well in every case.